# find average among positive or negative values in excel

Tags: excel, average

In a spreadsheet I have positive and negative values in a column. I need to find the average of both of them. How can I do this in excel / open office spreadsheet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SumIf() and divide by CountIf(), using ">0" or "<=0" as criteria. See help for both functions syntax, which is simple.